# Partial View Renders as blank new line

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

So I have a partial view in my layout page. When the page loads I can place break points in my partial view and see it hit the break points. I step through it and everything appears to be fine. There is only one spot where HTML can be generated, and when I put it in the immediate window I get exactly what I'm expecting. When I step over everything is fine. However, after I let it run and the page loads in the browser, the HTML doesn't show up in the view source. It comes in as an empty new line. I'm thinking that maybe I don't have the syntax right but I'm not sure what it is.

```
@*Imports display message, which field used here is Message (string) *@

<div>test</div> @* This works, and is rendered on the page. *@
@if (ViewBag.CriticalMessageCollection != null)
{
    ICollection<DisplayMessage> messages = ViewBag.CriticalMessageCollection as ICollection<DisplayMessage>;
    int count = 0;
    messages.ToList().ForEach(message =>
    {
        Html.Hidden("CriticalRootMessage_" + count, message.Message); @* This is not rendering, but shows correct HTML in immediate window. *@
        count++;
    });
}
```

Comment: Move the <div>test</div> to inside the if block. If that shows up try outputting the count value in a div and see it it is zero.

Comment: @PhilipSmith So if I moved it just as <div>test</div> within the foreach, it will throw a compilation error. CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'. However if I put it in a Html.Raw then it will behave the same where it's not rendered, yet running it in the immediate window yields the expected result.

Comment: How are you calling the PartialView in the layout?

Comment: @Jake If the div does not show when inside the if block, that would indicate that the if statement is returning false.Are you sure that the `CriticalMessageCollection` has a value?

Comment: @PhilipSmith CriticalMessageCollection does have a value. I ended up just scrapping the linq foreach and used a regular one and it worked. Not sure if this is a bug in .NET framework or user error here.    foreach (DisplayMessage message in messages)
    {
        <input type="hidden" id="CriticalRootMessage_@count" value="@message.Message" />
        count++;
    }

Comment: @Jake awesome. I'm pleased to see you have it working. I don't use .ForEach myself, so I can't comment on its reliability.